# Query table based on results of nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table (t1) that has messages and a thread_id.  Each thread ID corresponds to a conversation.  I run a query for terms in the messages and now I want to requery t1 based on the results of the query on the messages.  I cant do a nested one because the final result should be from the original t1.  Restating: I want all the conversations that contain certain words.  This is in postgresql 9.1.

Comment: What version of postgres are you using?

Comment: Without seeing your queries it's tough to tell what you're after. Perhaps you should look at [Common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

This would work with [Common Table Experssions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html), which are available from version 8.4 and up:

```
create table test_table1 (id serial, val1 integer, val2 text);
insert into test_table1 (val1, val2)
select
    v, 'test data ' || v
from generate_series(1,10000);


WITH
    t1 (id, val1, val2)
    as (
        select
            id, val1, val2
        from test_table1
        order by id asc
        limit 1000
    )

    ,t1_condition (id, condition)
    as (
        select
            id, val1 % 5 = 0
        from t1
        where val1 % 3 = 0
    )


select 
    t1.id, t1.val1, t1.val2,
    t1_condition.condition
from t1
left join t1_condition
on t1.id = t1_condition.id
```

Comment: A CTE is the right answer (+1), but `t1_condition.condition` in the example doesn't make much sense - would always be `TRUE` by definition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You're right. I edited to remove the %5 = 0 from the `where` clause. I did want the subselect in the example to not just return the full original table, though, because otherwise you could just do the condition test in the original select.